# Working with Pushstate and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working with NodeJS and HTML5 pushstate.
I have my index.html at "/" with a link to go to "/home/" via pushstate. All it's ok but if I refresh my page on /home/, my server return "Cannot GET /home/".

I just want "/home/" return my index.html file like "/"

My code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/home/', function(req, res, next) {
 //what to do here?
});

app.listen(3001);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop the `/` after`/home`:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
```

Regarding the `what to do here`, you can gather the data you need, and return the response. Eg: `res.end("Hello world!");`

If you want the static files to be served at `/home`, then:

```
app.use("/home", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Comment: Ok it's simple. The app.use on /home make the job